# TYPO3 7.3 extbase how to retrieve blob data?

Tags: typo3, extbase

We're migrating a 4.5 extension to 7.3 and we have blob values stored in mysql "longblob". Building a file from this blob value does not work any more.

The Extbase Variable Dump of the "blob" value is "NULL". Is there any example how to work with blob data with the new extbase?

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue in TCA, did not realised that internal_type now implicit adaptions to keep the same behaviour as an 4.5. Changed to classic text made it work as expected.

```
        'config' => array(
            'type' => 'group',
            'internal_type' => 'file',
            'uploadfolder' => 'uploads/tx_exasopmanager',
            'show_thumbs' => 1,
            'size' => 5,
            'allowed' => $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext'],
            'disallowed' => ''
        ),
```